# COMMAND_TIMED_SYNC invoke failed - Not Syncing, how to fix it?

Tags: error-log, coinbase-transaction

I get the following errors in 0.10.3.1:

```
2017-03-26 18:38:04.710 [P2P3]  ERROR   net.p2p src/p2p/net_node.inl:1504   [217.197.200.211:40472 INC] COMMAND_REQUEST_SUPPORT_FLAGS invoke failed. (-6, LEVIN_ERROR_CONNECTION_HANDLER_NOT_DEFINED)
2017-03-26 18:38:16.002 [P2P5]  ERROR   verify  src/cryptonote_core/blockchain.cpp:1012 coinbase transaction spend too much money (8.151603996028). Block reward is 8.144339615119(8.025326901329+0.119012713790)
2017-03-26 18:38:16.002 [P2P5]  ERROR   verify  src/cryptonote_core/blockchain.cpp:3339 Block with id: <aac8ed9ea67629e438175128ebbf5dd4d381934ce4d59487eb6e4e1bd1f7396b> has incorrect miner transaction
2017-03-26 18:38:27.352 [P2P7]  ERROR   verify  src/cryptonote_core/blockchain.cpp:1012 coinbase transaction spend too much money (8.151603996028). Block reward is 8.144339615119(8.025326901329+0.119012713790)
2017-03-26 18:38:27.352 [P2P7]  ERROR   verify  src/cryptonote_core/blockchain.cpp:3339 Block with id: <aac8ed9ea67629e438175128ebbf5dd4d381934ce4d59487eb6e4e1bd1f7396b> has incorrect miner transaction
2017-03-26 18:38:27.437 [P2P7]  ERROR   net.p2p src/p2p/net_node.inl:819    [199.231.85.122:18080 OUT] COMMAND_TIMED_SYNC invoke failed. (-3, LEVIN_ERROR_CONNECTION_DESTROYED)
2017-03-26 18:38:38.702 [P2P9]  ERROR   verify  src/cryptonote_core/blockchain.cpp:1012 coinbase transaction spend too much money (8.151603996028). Block reward is 8.144339615119(8.025326901329+0.119012713790)
2017-03-26 18:38:38.702 [P2P9]  ERROR   verify  src/cryptonote_core/blockchain.cpp:3339 Block with id: <aac8ed9ea67629e438175128ebbf5dd4d381934ce4d59487eb6e4e1bd1f7396b> has incorrect miner transaction
2017-03-26 18:38:38.786 [P2P9]  ERROR   net.p2p src/p2p/net_node.inl:819    [73.153.12.207:18080 OUT] COMMAND_TIMED_SYNC invoke failed. (-3, LEVIN_ERROR_CONNECTION_DESTROYED)
```

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 3):

I exported the blockchain from another node I have and imported to the failing node. Seems to have fixed the issue and it is now syncing and up to date.